# subject + V ing?

Tags: grammar

> I grew up with him playing football

I searched for it but coundn't get the answer I want. what is this usage called and how to use it correctly? like situations where it is used?

Comment: @ Astralbee thanks for the comment. But i'm still unclear about it does it require some verb in front of it to form object + V ing? or if I say "My thoughts on him joining this club is..." is this grammatically correct? –

Comment: "Thoughts" is plural, so you should use "are" not "is"... otherwise yes, fine. Have a look, you'll find lots of examples of subject + V ing. I'm watching him playing. My opinion on her marrying him. It's literally everyday speech.